# Finding the KKT Conditions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

So i'm revising for my exam and i'm struggling with this particular KKT question.

Here is a link to the question, I'd do it as a picture but I don't have enough reputation to do it.

1. Consider the following portfolio management problem for a large company. There is a market containing one riskless and $n$ risky assets, whose returns are given by $\left(R_{0}, \vec{R}\right),$ where $R_{0}>0$ is the (deterministic) return on the riskless asset and $\vec{R}=\left(R_{1}, \ldots, R_{n}\right)^{\mathrm{T}}$ are the returns on the risky assets. Let $\sigma_{i j}=\operatorname{Cov}\left(R_{i}, R_{j}\right),$ for $i, j=1 \ldots, n,$ and define the covariance matrix of the returns on risky assets by $\Sigma=\left(\sigma_{i j}\right)_{i, j=1, \ldots, n} .$ Assume that $\Sigma$ is invertible.

Let $X$ be some given random variable, representing an asset held by the company, and let $c_{i}=$ $\operatorname{Cov}\left(R_{i}, X\right),$ for $i=1, \ldots, n,$ and $\vec{c}=\left(c_{1}, \ldots, c_{n}\right)^{\top}$
Let $\overrightarrow{1}=(1, \ldots, 1)^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^{n},$ and define the constants $A=\overrightarrow{1}^{\top} \Sigma^{-1} \overrightarrow{1}$ and $E=\vec{c}^{\top} \Sigma^{-1} \overrightarrow{1}$
(a) Initially, the company seeks portfolio weights $\left(w_{0}, \vec{w}\right)$ which solve the following optimisation problem:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text { Minimise } f\left(w_{0}, \vec{w}\right)=\vec{w}^{\top} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \vec{w}+2 \vec{w}^{\top} \vec{c} \text { over }\left(w_{0}, \vec{w}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \hspace{5mm} (1) \\
\text { subject to } \quad g_{1}\left(w_{0}, \vec{w}\right)=w_{0}+\vec{w}^{\top} \overrightarrow{1}-1 \leq 0 \hspace{5mm} (1a) \end{array}
$$
(i) Explain briefly why (1) is a convex optimisation problem.

(ii) Show that the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions for (1) are equivalent to
$$
\begin{array}{r}
2 \Sigma \vec{w}+2 \vec{c}=\overrightarrow{0} \\
\lambda_{1}=0 \\
w_{0}+\vec{w}^{\top} \overrightarrow{1}-1 \leq 0
\end{array}
$$
and hence show that an optimal solution is given by
$$
\left(w_{0}, \vec{w}\right)=\left(1+E,-\Sigma^{-1} \vec{c}\right)
$$

My attempt: So for the critical point condition, I know I need to calculate the gradient of f and g but here's where I am struggling.

For the gradient of f, would it be 2Σw + 2c? I'm not too sure on the 2c.

for the gradient of g, i'm guessing it's just 1?

Feel a bit lost though and not sure if it's correct.

Comment: I see you reposted the same question with *my* MathJax edits. Please do not do this again on this website. Reposting the same exact question won't get you more attention, nor will it increase the likelihood you get an answer.

Comment: By the way, you could have taken out the "Here is a link to the question..." part. It is a dead giveaway.